# Show that $\sum _{k=1 } ^n \binom {n-1 } {k-1} x^{k-1 } (1-x)^{n-k }=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $\sum _{k=1 } ^n \binom {n-1 } {k-1} x^{k-1 }  (1-x)^{n-k }=1$

First $\sum _{k=0 } ^n \binom {n } {k } x^k (1-x)^{n-k } =1$, this follows from the binomial theorem. So this shouldn't be to hard. But I just got stuck and need help with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write $n=m-1, r=k-1$

Comment: Just write $k$ as $j+1$. The you have $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\ldots = (x+(1-x))^{n-1}=1.$$

Comment: In case you need to know, these are called Bernstein polynomials. They play very important role in computer aided design. The book "The NURBS Book" has an in depth treatment, along with several interesting properties.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{l}x^{l}y^{n-1-l}$, so letting $k=l+1$ and $y=1-x$ gives

$\displaystyle1=1^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k}$.